# Loop infinito com data stream no PHP

Tags: php, loop, stream

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo:

```
<?php
$Start = microtime(true);

$Code = <<<'Code'
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 300; $i++){
    echo '.';
}
Code;

include 'data://text/plain,'.$Code;

echo microtime(true) - $Start;
```

O PHP está entrando em um Loop infinito no qual não era pra entrar. Parece que a stream não consegue armazenar o valor da variável `$i`.
Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: a diretiva allow_url_include está ativada?

Comment: sim, está ativada...

Comment: Curioso. Nunca tinha visto esse tipo de código, porém ao efetuar os testes entendi o porque do loop infinito. `$i` nunca consegue ser incrementado pois parece que o escopo dela não existe.
Use `echo $i` e ajuste o tempo maximo de execução para 5 segundos para verificar.

Comment: Só aparece 0.. a variável `$i` não está sendo escrita...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelos testes o problema está no caractere **+**

Ele é suprimido no código final por não estar corretamente escapado.

Um código que funciona aqui no seu caso é esse:

```
$Start = microtime(true);

ini_set('max_execution_time', 5);

$Code = <<<'Code'
<?php
    for($i=0; $i < 300; $i++) { 
    echo $i . "\n";
};
?>
Code;


include_once 'data://text/plain,' . urlencode($Code);

echo microtime(true) - $Start;
?>
```

E aqui usando o que mencionou sobre php://memory

```
<?php
$Start = microtime(true);

ini_set('max_execution_time', 5);
$Code = <<<'Code'
<?php
    for($i=0; $i < 300; $i++) { 
    echo $i . "\n";
};
?>
Code;

 $fp = fopen('php://memory', 'rw'); 

fwrite($fp, urlencode($Code)); // escapando corretamente os caracteres 

fseek($fp, 0); // Retornando o ponteiro ao inicio do bloco de memória
include_once 'data://text/plain,' . stream_get_contents($fp); // incluindo como um arquivo

echo microtime(true) - $Start;
?>
```

Comment: E não quero o código fora do Heredoc. Quero o código dentro do Heredoc. Estou tentando achar um meio de executar o mesmo código, mas com a stream `php://memory` e procurar saber pq ocorreu esse problema.

Comment: Pelos meus teste, o problema está no $i++ do loop. Ele não fica assim no texto final e o $i jamais é incrementado. 
Com eval consegui um resultado que acho que funcionará para o seu caso.

Comment: Leia a minha resposta..

Comment: Que estranho. Como esse código funcionou?